# Fanfic where dragons resist magic more and more as they age, and talk about Twilight's mustache spell

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

I read a fanfic on [FimFiction](https://www.fimfiction.net/) that I can't find.

Dragons resist magic, and that gets stronger as they age.

And because of that, Twilight uses Spike as a test subject for her spells because they can't harm him, and as a strength measurement. If they can affect him, then her spells are strong.

One example of such a spell is the one that gives him a temporary moustache / mustache. Not sure which spelling the story used.

---

Quite sure it's not [Entry 7, Part 1 (Boast Busted) - The Poisoned Barb's Tale - Fimfiction](https://www.fimfiction.net/story/253652/26/the-poisoned-barbs-tale/entry-7-part-1-boast-busted)...

Or maybe it is? Somehow I read the first few chapters, which I totally forgot about? But is there any with a male Spike??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it must be [Entry 7, Part 1 (Boast Busted) - The Poisoned Barb's Tale - Fimfiction](https://www.fimfiction.net/story/253652/26/the-poisoned-barbs-tale/entry-7-part-1-boast-busted)...

Somehow I read the first few chapters, which I totally forgot about? But Fimfiction says nothing about the later chapters... However, downloading it would explain that... But is there any with a male Spike?? I haven't found any...

It even literally says "strength" in there.

> "Because you’re a dragon!" Dusk groans out in reply, clearly not happy answering what I feel to be a fair and reasonable question. "Your scales resist magic! You’re the best candidate I have for strength based spell checks!”

---

And I suppose the "stronger as they age" thing is both because it's a pretty common idea *and* comes from:

[Story Shuffle: Left Shaken](https://www.fimfiction.net/story/216813/8/story-shuffle/left-shaken): Where Discord says:

> a dragon as ancient

> as Behemoth

> is going to be largely immune to my more whimsical methods

Answer (score 2):

If you have misremembered and it was Sora who was the test subject then this would be [Boast Busters](https://www.fimfiction.net/story/328356/15/my-little-pony-soras-misadventures-in-equestria/boast-busters):

> "So, tell me again why I'm your magical test dummy, Twilight?" Sora asked as he stood in the Golden Oak Library, in the home area with Twilight Sparkle and Spike.
>
> "Well, you have magical powers, so you must be resistant to some magical spells. Plus, Spike's needed to cross off the different spells I made."

Then:

> "Ok. Now, hold still." Sora did as he was told, remaining standing where he had been since this morning.
>
> Twilight's aura charged around her horn as she readied the spell she was going to cast. She then fired a small beam at Sora, aimed at his face, the glowing light disappearing after a few seconds. A second later, Sora's upper lip began growing a bushy mustache, similar in color to his own hair.
>
> "Number twenty-five, hair growth spell!" Spike said as he crossed off the twenty-fifth spell.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not much into the KH Crossover scene, and it doesn't have age-based or draconic magical resistance.

Comment: Curiously, in the [episode S1E6 of the programme called Boast Busters](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1d84n0) Twilight casts the spell on Spike not Sora.